# why Android NDK log.h __android_log_print linker error

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I tried to use __android_log_print. But I getting linking error. I used makefile Android.mk :-

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_test_JniTest.cpp
    LOCAL_MODULE := com_test_JniTest
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I get error as :-

/Users/abc/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/src/main/jni/com_test_JniTest.cpp
Error:(29) undefined reference to `__android_log_print'

So how to link and use __android_log_print ?

Comment: Did you inclue `<android/log.h>` in `com_test_JniTest.cpp` ?

Comment: Yes, I included #include <android/log.h>. Note that there is no compilation error. Error comes when linking or executing application. It is linker error.

Comment: Try with `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -landroid`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with paths.

Search the path to liblog.so in your system and set the following:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L<path to liblog.so> -llog
```

for example:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
```

or if you are using Gradle you have to specify the lib into the build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "whatever"
            ldLibs "log"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found liblog.so at /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib. Then tried as -LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/Users/masum/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib -llog. But still same error.

Comment: You didn't write it but I prefer to ask, are you using Gradle to compile your code?

Comment: Actually I was trying new Gradle build. But couldn't do it. In step 1 got error. When I tried  ndk {
        moduleName "moduleNameHere"
    } Error:(20, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()'
Possible causes: The project 'NewTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin. NOTE that I have defined ndk.dir in local.properties also. So how to do it by Gradle

Comment: So can you confirm that the error you initially posted was related to a manual compilation (running ndk-build from command line) ?

Comment: Yes. Isn't it clear enough that I mentioned that I used Android.mk? So I have to use console and command ndk-build command. Later I tried Gradle build as well. But I get above mentioned error for Gradle :(

Comment: Two questions: 1) are you using cygwin? 2) can you post the command you use (or the content of the script you run)?

Comment: 1. I'm using mac. 2. I used command ndk-build in the same dir where I have Android.mk. The content of the script is given in the initial question. Later I updated as you suggested as  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/lib/ -llog. It didn't help. Get same error.